# String inside of a string Ex: pie = "He said "hi"" - C#

Tags: c#, string, escaping

In Visual Studio with C#, how can I declare a string inside of a string like this? I saw a few Stack Overflow pages like "Java string inside string to string", but didn't think any of them were the same as my question.

Basically if I have

```
"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"standalone="yes" ?>"
```

How can I declare this, or something like it, in my code as a string? Someone suggested double quotations to me around things like ""1.0"", but I couldn't get that to work.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Either escape the double quotes like this:

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"standalone=\"yes\" ?>"
```

or use a verbatim string (notice the leading **@** symbol in front of the string) like this:

```
@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""standalone=""yes"" ?>"
```

Answer (score 6):

Either:

```
@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8"" standalone=""yes"" ?>"
```

or

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\" ?>"
```

or more simply; use single quotes!

```
"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String myString = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"standalone=\"yes\" ?>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string myString = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8"" standalone=""yes"" ?>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the quotation marks: http://blogs.msdn.com/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/88415.aspx.